# How would I go about developing a file handler for Chrome and/or Chromium?

Tags: google-chrome, emacs, chromium

I would like to develop a browser plugin/extension (I'm not sure how they differ) for a particular (possibly new) file type.  To be very explicit, I would like to visit a file, "foo.org", using my browser in something like Drop Box or Google Drive and have the browser treat the file as Emacs would treat an org-mode file.  Eventually I would like to develop a full Emacs plugin/extension and be able to configure the browser to handle files with this plugin/extension based on the file extension or a file grokking heuristic.

Any solution that I develop will allow the editing to take place directly in the browser's tab area, i.e. a seamless solution (as opposed the useful but seamy Edit with Emacs solution referenced below).  In the same way that Chrome recognizes a spreadsheet or word document and invokes the appropriate Google Docs tool, I would like to get an Emacs-lite editor handle the foo.org file.  Another way to ask the question is: how do Google Docs tools get invoked within Chrome and perform the associated editing task.  And are these tools open source?

Answer (score 1):

You should consider building on [Ymacs](http://www.ymacs.org/) which is an Emacs-like editor in the browser.

For browser extensions, there is an [experimental downloads api](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/experimental.downloads.html). However, it doesn't let you monitor downloads at the moment. This is planned for the future:

> In the future, you will also be able to monitor and manipulate downloads.

However, you can probably just use some JavaScript and replace all links to `*.org` files with links that open in a tab running Ymacs. This should have the same effect--clicking a `*.org` link will open it in a new tab.

Take a look at [content scripts](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html) and the [tab api](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html) for documentation on how to inject a script into every page and how to open new tabs.

Comment: I'm not sure this is the right answer but it is a great suggestion.  Thanks, -pmr

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Edit with Emacs](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Edit_with_Emacs) , it should help you get (at least) part of the way there.

Comment: It would appear that my question was not clear enough.  I will edit it, but fwiw, I use Edit with Emacs all the time and find it to be a great tool but I am looking for a more seamless solution such that the editing takes place IN the browser's tab.